# What could make align use so much spacing?

Tags: spacing, align

Apologies in advance for not creating a compiling example, but when trying to duplicate just the related code to an empty .tex project, the phenomena does not appear.

I have the following code:

```
When queried for $x$, the algorithm outputs
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f^W_x} = \blockSize\cdot\sumOfOverflows[x]+\parentheses{\SSSInstance_{\window+\frameOffset} \mod \blockSize}
\end{align*}

Finally, we bound the error of the algorithm:
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f^W_x} &= \blockSize\cdot\sumOfOverflows[x]+\parentheses{\SSSInstance_{\window+\frameOffset} \mod \blockSize}\\
&=_{\eqref{eq:modulu}} \blockSize\cdot\sumOfOverflows[x] + \SSSInstance_{\window+\frameOffset}-\blockSize\cdot\sum_{t=W}^{\window+\frameOffset}{\overflowIndicator_t}\\
&\le_{\eqref{eq:ss-approx}} \blockSize\cdot\sumOfOverflows[x]+\sum_{t=\window}^{\window+\frameOffset}{x_t}+\blockSize-\blockSize\cdot\sum_{t=\window}^{\window+\frameOffset}{\overflowIndicator_t}\\
&\le_{\eqref{eq:overflow-count}}\blockSize\cdot\sum_{t=\frameOffset+1}^{\window+\frameOffset}{\overflowIndicator_t}+\sum_{t=\window}^{\window+\frameOffset}{x_t}+\blockSize-\blockSize\cdot\sum_{t=\window}^{\window+\frameOffset}{\overflowIndicator_t}
%\\&=\sum_{t=\frameOffset+1}^{\window+\frameOffset}{\overflowIndicator_t}+\sum_{t=\window}^{\window+\frameOffset}{x_t}+\blockSize-\blockSize\cdot\sum_{t=W+1}^{M+W-1}{\overflowIndicator_t}
\end{align*}
```

It creates the following pdf segment:

[image]

which looks fine.

Now if I try to remove the comment from the last line of the align* structure (i.e., add a single line to the equation flow), it adds huge amount of space before/after the align part:

[image]

When trying to reproduce the problem on a clean project, I had to remove the `eqrefs`, but then it worked, so this might be related to the problem.

> Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably have a very big display in the following page.

Comment: Which document class do you use? How are the macros `\blockSize`, `\sumOfOverflows`, `\parentheses`, `\SSSInstance`, `\window`, `\frameOffset`, etc. defined? Without such information, the situation you describe isn't reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @egreg :). I'm not sure what you mean though by having a bing display in the following page.

Comment: @Mico - I'm using \documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}. All of the macros are simple letters/expressions - block size is \frac{W}{k}, sumOfOverflows is B, SSSInstance is y, window is W, frame offset is M. \parentheses is simply parentheses (\newcommand{\parentheses}[1]{ \left({#1}\right)} ).

I don't think the problem has anything to do with the macros. Thanks for your interest !

Comment: @DW The problem is quite certainly caused by a large object (such as a display) in the page that follows, which causes TeX to break the page without having sufficient material to fill it up.